# Activestorage image saved in blob but not showing in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm following the rails ActiveStorage guide. I've successfully saved the image to the blob table in the local database (the attachment table is empty). But I can't seem to show it in the view:

```rb
<%= url_for(@comment.images) if @comment.images %>
```

does not work nor does:

```rb
     <% @comments.each do |c| %>
        <%= c.body %>

        <%= url_for(c.images) if c.images %>

      <% end %>
```

Showing other values of comment works, so this is specific to the images. I've also tried adding .url to "images." And I've tried image_tag instead of url_for. And looping through the images. And image_tag url_for (instead of using just one of them). And using representation. No luck in all of these cases. I'd really appreciate any help.

And my model

```rb
  has_many_attached :images
```

application.js

```js
//= require activestorage


import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"


Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

controller

```rb
    private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:body, images: [])
    end
```

Comment: Are those images `representable?` could you please check the result for  `@comment.images.first.representable?`

Comment: Have you looked into the section for how [Displaying Images, Videos, and PDFs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#displaying-images-videos-and-pdfs) from `Active Storage Overview` documentation ?

Comment: @SampatBadhe Hey Sampat, thank you for your comment. I got this error: undefined method `representable' for nil:NilClass. I also tried ```<%= image_tag i.representation(resize: '500x500') %>``` but nothing showed. ( "i" since I was looping through them)

Comment: Are you sure images are exists for comment? Could you please check `@comment.images.attached?` returns true or false?

Comment: @SampatBadhe Thank you -- you're exactly right, it returns false. What does this mean? The blob table shows the images, so I just assumed ("metadata" is empty though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change file upload form from

```rb
<%= form.file_field :images, multipart: true, direct_upload: true %>
```

to

```rb
<%= form.file_field :images, multiple: true, direct_upload: true %>
```

It was not uploading before, and somebody had suggested switching to "multipart." It solved the uploading in appearance but it was not attaching the image.

I guess the uploading in appearance also works now because I tweaked something as I frantically tried multiple things.

Now the attachments table is populating with images. Before only the blob table was populating.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified has_many_attached, so @comment.images will contain an array of images, So the following code will display the first image of your comment.

```
     <%= image_tag(@comment.images.first) if @comment.images.attached? %>
```

If you want to display all images you can iterate through @comment.images array and display each image

Comment: Thank you for the comment. As mentioned, I tried looping. It didn't work.

Comment: Are you able to display the first image using above code ?

Comment: No, because my problem was unique (please see the answer I posted)